# Anyone know how do i get the real time feeds on gas station price in US via webservice version?

Tags: iphone

Anyone has pointers on how to get real time US gas station feeds via webservice ?

I'm trying to develop an iphone app that give users real time gas station price near their location. Currently i was wondering is there a legit government service that produce real time gas station price in the US on a daily basis?

I heard about http://gasbuddy.com/ but i don't know where they get the data source from and was not sure if i should base on their data as well.

On the other hand, there is a bunch of iphone apps on the apple store that show the gas price info. I'm clueless on how did the developers got their source from to get the nearest gas station price locations.

Anyone has any suggestion? Thanks for the info :- )

Answer (score 1):

According to http://gasprices.mapquest.com, they get their information from the Oil Price Information Service (OPIS) at http://www.opisnet.com/.

Comment: Thanks for the answer. I wonder how i can access the info if they don't have any web service provided? By the way, anyone who wrote an iphone app regarding this use case would like to share some input on how you do it?

Answer (score 0):

Also there is a new website launched called www.mygasfeed.com. They are developing an API for mobile and web developers.

But they need a strong community to update gas prices.